# Getting the grease pencil to render in a 360 panorama

Tags: grease-pencil

I drew with the grease pencil different furniture. In the end I want to have a 360 panorama video to enjoy it with a VR gear.

My problem is, when i render the scene, all the meshs are distorted as they should but the grease pencil doesn't change. But shouldn't it change (like be distorted) by the panoramic equirectangular setting of the camera ?
So I'm searching for a solution so that my grease pencil stroke fit in the 360 panorama view ?

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I would like to render a panorama with grease pencil, too.

Comment: @KonCode Hi ! Sadly no i haven't find any solution :/ I think the only way around is to convert the grease pencil path into mesh. But it's a lot of work and a lot of cleaning.